# How to create a program that gives infinite slope?

Tags: python

Write a program that determines the slope of a line given two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2). Your input should be 4 integer values representing the two points. In the case of any improper slopes, output INFINITY.

this is what i did

```
x1 = int(input("Enter the value of x1:"))
y1 = int(input("Enter the value of y1:"))
x2 = int(input("Enter the value of x2:"))
y2 = int(input("Enter the value of y2:"))
slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
print(slope)
if slope is slope/0:
print(infinite)
else:
print(slope)
```

Comment: Computers are dumb, you should tell them what to do... PROPERLY!

Comment: And your question is?  Did you encounter errors? How exactly can we help you? Hint: maybe check for infinite slope before calculating it.

Comment: Don't use `is` to test for equality. Use `==`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```

Will cause a problem (divison by 0) if `x1 == x2`. Better to test for this before you blow up

```
if x1 == x2:
    slope = float("inf")
else:
    slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
print(slope)
```

You can also do this in one line

```
slope = float("inf") if x1 == x2 else (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
```